# Запуск контроллера по времени

Tags: asp.net-core

Имеется контроллер, который обращается к google таблице, скачивает её и парсит.
Эта таблица может изменяться и хотелось бы раз или два в день дёргать этот контроллер.

Что можно использовать, чтобы дёргать этот контроллер в определённое время без моего участия (таймер или что-то подобное).

Comment: Можете использовать `cron-job.org`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за идеи!
Задача решается использованием Quartz.
Создаётся задача и настраивается её выполнение с нужным интервалом.

Сделал примерно как [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/24.1.php)

Comment: Это лишь один из способов решения, не без недостатков. Например обратите внимание на комментарий: https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/24.1.php#comment-2622173555

Comment: @PetrAbdulin я правильно понял, что служба будет работать, если комп в windows включен? А если я его не включаю неделю, то как служба дёрнет контроллер (сервис)?

Comment: По ссылке выше говорится о ASP NET под IIS на Windows хостинге, там действительно есть проблема засыпания пула, если его не дергать с определенной периодичностью. Но если используется хостинг на линуксе и NET Core, то по сути запускается консольное приложение, которое работает в фоне и не имеет подобной проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте системный планировщик задач или напишите сервис. Средствами веб-сервера эта задача не решается.

Comment: т.е. если я опубликовал приложение на azure, то только самому дёргать этот контроллер?

Comment: @alladuh, в азуре можно и сервисы делать

Comment: @alladuh а что вас смущает? Вам же это и нужно? Можно в принципе задачу эту реализовывать не как метод контроллера, а сразу в тулзе или сервисе.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin вот тут собственно и встаёт вопрос, я первый раз публикую, и хотел бы узнать, чем конкретно нужно воспользоваться

Comment: @alladuh для вызова обработки через интервал тем чем я уже написал: планировщик или сервисы. В вашем случае достаточно первого.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin У вас ASP NET или ASP NET Core?

Comment: @ГеннадийП ASP .NET Core